# Add extra column with count function in linq to query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am working on a Asp.net Core project and using CodeFirst and have a query with sql syntax like this

```
  SELECT PartID, PartName, PartLevel,
       (SELECT   COUNT(ID) AS Expr1
       FROM   dbo.systemparts
       WHERE(MSys.PartID = PartLevel)) AS ChildCount
  FROM dbo.systemparts AS MSys
```

sample output

[image: sample output sql statment]

**My Model**

```
public class SystemPart
{
    [Key]
    public int PartID { get; set; }

    public string PartName { get; set; }

    public int PartLevel { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to change it in linq to query string or lambda exporession in index action. But i cant handle `ChildCount` feild. How can i do it?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto added more info in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally define a ViewModel for this, since you want to return it to a view:

```
public class SystemPartViewModel
{
    public int PartId { get; set; }
    public string PartName { get; set; }
    public int PartLevel { get; set; }
    public int ChildCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do the query quite easily with LINQ:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var query = 
        from msys in _context.SystemParts
        let childCount = _context.SystemParts.Count(x => x.PartLevel == msys.PartID)
        select new SystemPartViewModel
        {
            PartId = msys.PartID,
            PartName = msys.PartName,
            PartLevel = msys.PartLevel,
            ChildCount = childCount
        };

    return View(await query.ToListAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the below LINQ query, which will return collection of `antonymous` type.

```
context.systemparts.Select(p=> new {
         PartId = p.Partid,
         PartName = p.PartName,
         PartLevel = p.PartLevel,
         ChildCount = context.systemparts.Where(q=>q.PartLevel = p.Partid).Count()
});
```

if your view Model contains the property for ChildCount, then you can map that model in the Select, like below -

```
context.systemparts.Select(p=> new ViewModelName {
             PartId = p.Partid,
             PartName = p.PartName,
             PartLevel = p.PartLevel,
             ChildCount = context.systemparts.Where(q=>q.PartLevel = p.Partid).Count()
    });
```

Comment: In Model there is not `ChildCount` field. How can i pass ChildCount in Model?

Comment: You need to add ChildCount in the model, then you can return `new ModelName{}` instead of anonymous model `new {}`;